# Glossaries package - Hierachical acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

How can I generate a tree of acronyms? Something like that:

[image]

This is what i tried to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{mamals}{mamals}{mamals}
\newacronym[parent=mamals]{dog}{DOG}{One dog}
\newacronym[parent=mamals]{cat}{CAT}{One cat}
\newacronym[parent=mamals]{donkey}{DKY}{One donkey}

\newacronym{insect}{insect}{insect}
\newacronym[parent=insect]{ant}{ANT}{One ant}
\newacronym[parent=insect]{bee}{BEE}{One bee}
\newacronym[parent=insect]{wasp}{WSP}{One wasp}

\begin{document}
\acrshort{dog} \acrshort{cat} \acrshort{donkey} \acrshort{ant} \acrshort{bee} \acrshort{wasp}

\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

But I cant figure out:

[image]

Thanks!